# Perform Load Testing for a newly developed application

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I want to know how to perform Load Testing.

Requirement is

- Total number of concurrent users at any given time are **5000**
- Request a session once every **40 seconds** on average
- Each session requires the web application consume an average **12Kb** download bandwidth.

Note:
We need to perform load testing for a newly developed web application to assess the data rate required for the hosting webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad because the implementation will be different depending on the load testing tool choice, I would recommend taking the following steps:

1. Get familiar with the web applications performance testing general concept, i.e. [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=perftestingguide)
2. If time allows it would be good to read [ISTQB Performance Testing Specialist Syllabus](https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/performance-testing/performance-testing-materials-for-download.html) as well
3. Then you need to choose a load testing tool, if there is no standard one in your organization you need to either acquire a commercial license or go for [free and open source solution](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview), an example comparison of the most outstanding/popular free and open source load testing tools: [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)
4. Once you choose the tool then consult its documentation with regards to implementing your scenario or ask a tool-specific question using relevant [SO tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)